# Why do we use keras back-end command in codes?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import backend as K
```

What is the reason behind using the command—>
`from keras import backend as K`

What does it do? I would appreciate it if anyone explains it the simple way so that it does not get complicated in the mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information on what Keras backend actually is [here](https://keras.io/ko/backend/) or [here](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html).
In simpler terms to understand what Keras backend actually is

> Keras is a model-level library that provides high-level building blocks for developing deep learning models. Keras does not provide low-level operations such as tensor multiplication and convolution. Instead, it relies on a specialized, well-optimized tensor library that serves as Keras' "backend engine". Instead of choosing one single tensor library and tying your Keras implementation to that library, Keras handles the problem in a modular way, allowing you to seamlessly connect multiple different backend engines to Keras.

Keras backend will allow you to write custom code or in a particular case a new "Keras module" for your use case that can support Theano and/or Tensorflow both. Like instead of `tf.placeholder()` you could write `keras.backend.placeholder()` which will work across both the libraries mentioned earlier.